# ansible ec2_metric_alarm will not attach to auto scaling policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, boto

So I am trying to use the ansible ec2_metric_alarm task to create a cloud watch alarm that monitors my auto scaling group and will activate an auto scaling policy if the cpu usage for the ASG goes above or below a certain point.

```
   - ec2_metric_alarm:
      aws_access_key: '{{ ami_access }}'
      aws_secret_key: '{{ ami_secret }}'
      state: present
      region: "{{regi}}"
      name: "{{item.names}}"
      metric: "CPUUtilization"
      namespace: "AWS/EC2"
      statistic: Average
      comparison: "{{item.compare}}"
      threshold: "{{item.limits}}"
      period: 60
      evaluation_periods: 1
      unit: "Percent"
      description: "{{item.desc}}"
      dimensions: {'AutoScalingGroupName':'{{auto_sc}}'}
      alarm_actions: "{{item.pol}}"
     with_items:
      - names: "cpuUP_{{auto_sc}}"
        compare: ">="
        limits: "20.0"
        desc: "This will alarm when the average cpu usage of the ASG is         greater than 20% for 1 minute"
        pol: "cpuUP_{{auto_sc}}_policy"
      - names: "cpuDown_{{auto_sc}}"
        compare: "<="
        limits: "10.0"
        desc: "This will alarm when the average cpu usage of the ASG is less than 10% for 1 minute"
        pol: "cpuDown_{{auto_sc}}_policy"
```

For some reason I cannot just use the literal name of my auto scaling policies (which would be "cpuDown_test3_policy" and "cpuUP_test3_policy") and I need to use something called an "arn syntax" because my error messages keep complaining of an invalid Arn syntax.

How do I find the arn syntax or convert my auto scaling policy names into arn syntax?

For reference here is the error message I receive when I try to run my playbook as is:

```
TASK [ec2_metric_alarm]     ********************************************************
failed: [localhost] => (item={u'pol': u'cpuUP_test3_policy', u'desc': u'This wil
l alarm when the average cpu usage of the ASG is greater than 20% for 1     minute',
 u'compare': u'>=', u'limits': u'20.0', u'names': u'cpuUP_test3'}) =>     {"failed":
 true, "item": {"compare": ">=", "desc": "This will alarm when the average     cpu u
sage of the ASG is greater than 20% for 1 minute", "limits": "20.0",     "names": "c
puUP_test3", "pol": "cpuUP_test3_policy"}, "msg": "BotoServerError: 400 Bad     Requ
est\n<ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://monitoring.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-08-    01/\">\n
  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>ValidationError</Code>\n        <Messa
ge>Invalid arn syntax: cpuUP_test3_policy</Message>\n  </Error>\n      <RequestId>d8
97c79a-01db-11e6-92d5-5fa534a149e9</RequestId>\n</ErrorResponse>\n"}
failed: [localhost] => (item={u'pol': u'cpuDown_test3_policy', u'desc':     u'This w
ill alarm when the average cpu usage of the ASG is less than 10% for 1     minute', 
u'compare': u'<=', u'limits': u'10.0', u'names': u'cpuDown_test3'}) =>     {"failed"
: true, "item": {"compare": "<=", "desc": "This will alarm when the average     cpu 
usage of the ASG is less than 10% for 1 minute", "limits": "10.0", "names":     "cpu
Down_test3", "pol": "cpuDown_test3_policy"}, "msg": "BotoServerError: 400     Bad Re
quest\n<ErrorResponse xmlns=\"http://monitoring.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-08-    01/\">
\n  <Error>\n    <Type>Sender</Type>\n    <Code>ValidationError</Code>\n        <Mes
sage>Invalid arn syntax: cpuDown_test3_policy</Message>\n  </Error>\n      <RequestI
d>d8b33ea6-01db-11e6-82db-8bfc9e3af9a2</RequestId>\n</ErrorResponse>\n"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read this link which explains [Amazon Resource Name.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) 
Here is an excerpt from the link provided.

> Amazon Resource Names (ARNs) uniquely identify AWS resources. We require an ARN when you need to specify a resource unambiguously across all of AWS, such as in IAM policies, Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) tags, and API calls.

Here is an example of what alarm_actions: should look like..

```
alarm_actions: ["arn:aws:autoscaling:region:account-id:scalingPolicy:policyid:autoScalingGroupName/groupfriendlyname:policyname/policyfriendlyname"]
```

You should create a Scaling Policy 1st and use the registered output to grab the arn of the scaling policy you want to use.

Here is an example..

```
- name: Scale Out policy
  local_action:
  module: ec2_scaling_policy
    state: present
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    name: "Name-ScaleOutPolicy"
    adjustment_type: "ChangeInCapacity"
    asg_name: "name_of_autoscale_group"
    scaling_adjustment: "-1"
    min_adjustment_step: "1"
    cooldown: "30"
  register: so_result
```

Now you can set your metric alarm to use the scaling policy arn, like so.

```
alarm_actions: ['{{ so_result["arn"] }}']
```